# getting avg of column based on the result set

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a select statement that divides the count of sales by country, priceBanding (see example below)

[image]

The select statement looks like follows:

```
SELECT p.[Price Band]
,t.[Country]
,o.COUNT([Order]) as [Order Count]
FROM #price p (temp table)
INNER JOIN country t ON p.CountryCode = t.countryCode
INNER JOIN sales o ON o.salesValue >= p.startPrice and s.salesValue < p.endPrice
```

What i want to be able to do is based on this result i want to get an avg of the unit count i.e. For all orders that are under 20 what is the avg unit counts and the same for all others. How can i do this?

Its most likely simple but I cant think through it.

What I am after:

[image]

So as you can see, in the price band <20 in UK the order count is 50, and the avg Units of that is 2. As i mentioned earlier, I want the Avg Units of all orders that are under 20 (which is 50 in the picture).

Is that clearer?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

[image]

The first table: assume it to be the source

And the second table gets the avg, that's what I am after.

Comment: Can you share the result you'd like to get for this sample data? It's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also p.Id = c.Id and p.ID = s.ID does make any sense, where are the FKs ?

Comment: Also, if you show us the original table data, or at least a subset of it, that would be nice.

Comment: You select `t.[Country]`, but there are no table `t` in the from clause. Perhaps you mean `c.[Country]`? (Similar o/s confusion.)

Comment: hi apologies i should've been more clearer earlier. But does that make more sense?

Comment: It's still not clear what you're after.

It seems like you want to be able to calculate the "Avg Units" value, as indicated by your "What I am after" table, but you've not really explained what this value represents.

In conflict with, or perhaps in addition to, this requirement is your statement "I want the Avg Units of all orders that are under 20 (which is 50 in the picture)", which seems to suggest you want the sum of Avg units for all price bands with an order count <20. That said, this number is actually 40 and not 50, so your requirement remains a bit opaque.

Comment: please see the image above i will just add, maybe that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you just use `avg()`?

```
SELECT p.[Price Band], t.[Country],
       o.COUNT(*) as [Order Count],
       AVG(Items)
FROM #price p INNER JOIN
     country t
     ON p.CountryCode = t.countryCode INNER JOIN
     sales o
     ON o.salesValue >= p.startPrice and s.salesValue < p.endPrice
GROUP BY p.[Price Band], t.[Country]
ORDER BY t.[Country], p.[Price Band]
```

Note:  SQL Server does integer division of integers (so 3/2 = 1 not 1.5) and similarly for `AVG()`.  It is more accurate to use a decimal point number.  An easy way is to use `AVG(items * 1.0)`.

Comment: Cheers. Thats what I just before but I wanted to know if theres a simpler way, thanks.